# C# Change background color of a table cell inTableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am trying to change the background color of a table cell inside a `TableLayoutPanel` programmatically. The cells can either be `null` or taken by a user control during runtime (always changing).

I was doing this:

```
TableName.GetControlFromPosition(column, row).BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
```

Of course, this only works if there is something at that cell. How can I also change the properties of a null cell at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there really is no such thing a `TableLayoutPanelCell`. The 'cells' are strictly **virtual**.

You can use the `CellPaint` event to draw any `BackColor` onto any 'cell', empty or not:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row == e.Column)
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.AliceBlue))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
    else
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(123, 234, 0)))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
}
```

[image]

Of course the colors and the conditions are up to you..

**Update:** Note once more that you cannot color a certain 'cell' because there **are** no `TableLayoutPanelCells`! No such class, neither controls nor even objects. It just doesn't exist! A TLP is **not** made up of 'cells'. It is made up of rows and columns only.

So to color a 'cell' you need to code a suitable condition in the `CellPaint` event, which is the closest .NET comes to using the name 'cell'.

You can use simple formulas or explicit enumerations to create the color layout you want, depending on you needs.

Here are two more elaborate examples:

For a simple **checkerboard** layout use this condition:

```
if ((e.Row + e.Column) % 2 == 0)
```

For a **freeform** layout collect all color values in a `Dictionary<Point>, Color` ;

```
Dictionary<Point, Color> cellcolors = new Dictionary<Point, Color>();
cellcolors.Add(new Point(0, 1), Color.CadetBlue);
cellcolors.Add(new Point(2, 4), Color.Blue);
..
..
..
```

and write:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (cellcolors.Keys.Contains(new Point(e.Column, e.Row )))
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(cellcolors[new Point(e.Column, e.Row )]))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
    else
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(defaultColor))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
}
```

Comment: How can I specify which Cell to color with this event? `TableLayoutCellPaintEvenArgs` only has `get` for the `Row` and `Column` so I can't set those values. I have a 2D array that represents the table which is filled with 1's and 0's (always changing). I want to color the cells where there is a `1` in the array. Right now, the event is painting the whole table no matter the condition.

Comment: This event is called for each 'cell' and on every refresh. So to set certain cells' colors you need to code their row/column indices in the conditions. Depending on your needs this can be as simple as a formula or as tedious as enumerating each cell. See my update for two more examples! - You wrote: _Right now, the event is painting the whole table no matter the condition._ This surely is not true, or rather: Yes all 'cells' always get painted using this event, but __always according to the condition you write__.

Comment: Thank you so much! It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

when the cell is null, you can not set it's BackColor property. When set color, you should check if it is null. And you can set color of controls in the cells rather than cell's BackColor.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rATne.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how I should do it then? I have 64 cells. I was thinking of making 64 panels and placing one in each cell. Then putting the user controls in each panel. What do you think?

Comment: yeah of course you can get what you want as what you say .
I did as you say.

 `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        panel2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        panel5.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        panel7.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
    }`

you can set any panel's BackColor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
tlp.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150,0,0,0);

That should do the trick….