# C# change table row color when mouse hover

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a table layout panel in my winform, and I want to add an effect to the rows whenever the mouse is hover a row.

I think I need to make a Mouse_over action over the table, and then detect the row number of the table, and then iterate on each cell on the row and change it's back color.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the row number.

Any ideas please?

*EDIT:* I am adding rows to the table dynamically, I have set of buttons and when I click one it deletes all old rows from the table and adds new rows that are related to this button.
This is the way I add new rows:

```
tlp.RowCount++;
tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
tlp.Controls.Add(new Label() { ... }, cellIDX, rowIDX);
// adding more columns //
```

and to remove old rows I loop through all rows from bottom to top, removes all related controls of current cell, then I remove style and row num like so:

```
tlp.RowStyle.RemoveAt(rowNum);
tlp.RowCount--;
```

Comment: Since the cells of `TableLayoutPanel` contains controls, the mouse events will raise sometimes for `TableLayoutPanel` and sometimes for controls.

Comment: Maybe if you share more about the actual requirement which made you think about `TableLayoutPanel` or tell more about controls which are hosted in `TableLayoutPanel` a more practical answer could be shared.

Comment: Contrary to  popular believe the TLP does not contain any Cells. See [here for a discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733557/c-sharp-change-background-color-of-a-table-cell-intablelayoutpanel/38736243#38736243)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

As there actually are [no `Cells` in a `TableLayouPanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733557/c-sharp-change-background-color-of-a-table-cell-intablelayoutpanel/38736243#38736243) all you can do is

- detect where th mouse is
- paint the `TLP` in the `CellPaint` event.

Since your `TLP` most likely will contain controls they also need to detect whether the mouse is on them..

Here is an example:

First a class level variable to store the current row:

```
 int tlpRow = -1;
```

Next a `CellPaint` event that can color a row:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row == tlpRow) 
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(123, 234, 45, 67)))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
}
```

Next we need detection routines. First one for the `TLP`:

```
bool testTLP(TableLayoutPanel tlp,  Point pt)
{
    var rs = tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles;
    var rh = 0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < rs.Count; i++)
    {
        if (pt.Y > rh && pt.Y <= rh + rs[i].Height )
        {
            if (tlpRow != i)
            {
                tlpRow = i;
                tableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        }
        rh += rs[i].Height;
    }
    tlpRow = -1;
    return false;
}
```

It loops over all rows and adds up the heights until it has found the right one. Then it stores the row index and triggers the `CellPaint` event.

We can use the same routine for the controls:

```
bool testTLP(TableLayoutPanel tlp)
{
    Point point = tlp.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    return testTLP(tlp, point);
}
```

We simply calculate the mouse position relative to the `TLP` and call the same test.

Note that this test only for 1 level of nesting. If you have deeper nested control you may need to expand on the test somewhat..!

We also need to call the tests; the `TLP` test can be called in the `MouseMove`:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    testTLP(tableLayoutPanel1, e.Location);
}
```

The controls get hooked up all together maybe like this:

```
void hookUpControls(TableLayoutPanel tlp)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in tlp.Controls)
    {
        ctl.MouseMove += (s, e) => { testTLP(tlp); };
    }
}
```

I use the MouseMove event as the MouseEnter sometimes slipped through in my tests..

If you add controls later you need to hook the up as well. Make sure not to hook one up multiple times!

Most likely you want to reset the coloring when leaving the `TLP`:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point tplPoint = tableLayoutPanel1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    if (!tableLayoutPanel1.ClientRectangle.Contains(tplPoint))  tlpRow = -1;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Note: when you add Controls **dynamically** you need to hook the up as well. Here is an example:

```
Label lbl = new Label() { Text = "newbie" };
lbl.MouseMove += (ss, ee) => { testTLP(tlp, lbl); }; 
tlp.Controls.Add(lbl, cellIDX, rowIDX);
```

If you find the coloring flickers you can simply add a DoubleBuffered subclass:

```
class DoubleBufferedTLP : TableLayoutPanel
{
    public DoubleBufferedTLP()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

To do so you need to add to the project, compile, check to see it appears in the ToolBox. If you want to you can simply change the two sponts in the form_designer class..

Comment: I would also handle `MouseLeave` event of `TableLayoutPanel`, to set `tlpRow=-1` *if* the mouse is not in table bounds.

Comment: @Reze: Yes, I also need to change we are really off and not just on a child control..

Comment: @TaW yet again thank you for the detailed answer. I tried it on my code and it doesn't work and I think it is related to the way I add syles when I add new rows to the TLP. I edit my question to show more details. This is my situation: I have buttons, that each time I click one of them, I delete all the rows from the table, then I add specific new rows that are attached to the specific button. so the rows are beeing added dynamiclly. the add and delete of the rows and controls inside the rows works good, just the coloring I am hvaing some issues. this also answers why I am using a TLP.

Comment: @Taw I think I fixed that bug... it was related to the fact that I don't added height to the row style. thogh now it works I still get a flickr effect when coloring the table. any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: See my updated answer! The flicker goes away with doublebuffering and hooking up new controls works fine that way, too.

Comment: @TaW thank you! can you explain a bit about the doubl buffered? why it works? because with a lo of rows the labels have also a bit of flickr, should I add them as well a double buffer? becuase they have a transparent back color

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure just the TLP needs it. Many controls that receive a lot of Paint events will flicker unless you switch on double buffering. Unfortunatly only the Form exposes the property; for all others we need to subclass to turn it on. (Exception: PictureBox, which has it on by default, but this was meant to be used for extensive graphics..) -  It means that the new surface is prepared in the background and only loaded when finished.  [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TaW, so in that case what can I do with the labels?

Comment: Well, I you really need you can subclass Label just as well; but are you really sure they flicker? Note that their MouseMove will cause the TLP to repaint, so they may seem to flicker although it really is the TLP. Did you sublass TLP?

Comment: @TaW I created a new UserControl, that inherits from the TableLayoutPanel, then in the Designer I changed my tlp to be the new type control I made. though I changed it just in one place in the designer. are those the steps I needed to do?

Comment: a) you have created, I hope, not a UserControl but a CustomControl. Not the same thing. CCs are subclasses, UCs are like Forms but still controls. UCs have a designer and you can add controls, CCs don't have a desiger. b) there are __two__ spots not one! One is the declaration at the end, the other the instantiation in the 'forbidden'  `InitializeComponent` part. You need to change __both__!

Comment: @TaW thank you, it's still a bit laggy, but works better.

Comment: It is quick and not laggy here, but then, my test tlp is rather small. How large is yours? how many controls on it?

Comment: I have about 5. maybe it's because I am using Transparent color?

Comment: No. I must be an error in the MouseLeave code. It only happens sometimes but never when I comment out the MouseLeave . Corrected!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Comment: @Taw sure my friend I forgot I was sure I already accepted it... thank you again!