# c# add objects to table rows dynamiclly

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am trying to do something like this but I don't know how:

I have a table in c# which I increase and decrease during runtime.

Each row contains data, that is being parsed from an object.

I want to get an access to the object that the line is parsing, some a pseudo of it would be:

`if (table.row.object == selectedObject)`

I can't do it from the row number or something because the rows are being removed and inserted, each time with different objects.

any ideas, please?

*EDIT:* I am using TableLayoutPanel to work with a table, and this is how I add rows and removes them:

I am adding rows to the table dynamically, I have set of buttons and when I click one it deletes all old rows from the table and adds new rows that are related to this button.

This is the way I add new rows:

```
tlp.RowCount++;
tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
tlp.Controls.Add(new Label() { ... }, cellIDX, rowIDX);
// adding more columns //
```

and to remove old rows I loop through all rows from bottom to top, removes all related controls of the current cell, then I remove style and row num like so:

```
tlp.RowStyle.RemoveAt(rowNum);
tlp.RowCount--;
```

thank you

you can also see a previous question I had related to this subject:
[C# change table row color when mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316692/c-sharp-change-table-row-color-when-mouse-hover)

Comment: Is it a DataTable or which kind of table is it? When do you need this to be executed?

Comment: Show us the code you're using to generate / bind your table data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a new column in the table (call it original_row_no) and set the row values into that, before you start your insertion/deletion process. That way you can reference the row directly (this is in response to your final line which says "I can't do it from the row number or something because the rows are being removed and inserted, each time with different objects."

A better way is to have a unique id in the table and run your references against that.

It is much more easier to help if you show the code you are trying.