# C# form tablelayoutpanel using cells

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Hello I am making simple battleships for my school project and I am almost done but I have one problem and it is ship placement. I have made a small TableLayoutpanel with a label in every cell and every label has click function on it, if I click on the label, its text is changed from X to O to represent a ship but I don't know how to change the label in the cell next to it so no matter on which label I click it would make 2 tile ship. I saw in every table layout has variable tabIndex and there is a number for every cell so I taught if I could subtract 1 from that number pick that cell an change it as well but I am not really sure how to do that or if it is possible.

Also, I wonder if there is a way to pick a random cell from TableLayeoutPanel and change it. Let's say pick one cell out of nine and its text color would change to red.

thanks for every suggestion.

Comment: I do not like using Tablelayoutpanel.  Instead of create my own array of panels by using a regular panel and adding my own array of panels.  The layout panel is very limited on the properties and often I get into the same issue you are having.

Comment: A few [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316692/c-sharp-change-table-row-color-when-mouse-hover/39317064#39317064) on working with a TLP - Also see `tlp.GetControlFromPosition`!