# How to check the color of the cells surrounding any cell in a tableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to check the color of the cells surrounding any given cell in a tableLayoutPanel.

Example:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Assuming e is the given cell. Then I want to check the color of the surrounding cells (b, d, f and h).

I am making a Conway's Game of Life.

Comment: You should have a data model that contains the necessary information about the state of the cells. The UI should reflect the model. Checking neighboring cells then would be simple array addressing.

Comment: Cells of TableLayoutPanel doesn't exists as a control and doesn't have such `BackColor` property. Read this post to know [How to set cell color in tableLayoutPanel dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064499/how-to-set-cell-color-in-tablelayoutpanel-dynamically). Then based on the solution which you use to setting back color. You can store back colors in a data structure like array. Also you can host panels in cells and set back color for those panels. In both cases you can simply extract what the back color is.

Comment: In first case `GetControlFromPosition` helps you to find hosted panel at row and column and the `BackColor` of the control is what you need. In second case, the element at specified index of array which contains back colors is what you are looking for.

Comment: [Here is another post to study](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733557/c-sharp-change-background-color-of-a-table-cell-intablelayoutpanel/38736243#38736243) ;-)

Comment: You may want to consider a DataGridView or even do all drawing yourself. (recommended) TLP is, as the name implies for laying out controls, not for drawing..